# Istio 1.11.0 to 1.14.1 operator upgrade issue

Tags: azure-aks, istio

When I upgrade Istio from 1.11.0 to 1.14.1
Istio operator shows status as “RECONCILING”
Istio operator log is looping into the below error

Can some body guide me how we can fix the above issues (details are given below)

```
NextGen-ADA-Istio % ~/Downloads/istio-1.14.1/bin/istioctl version
client version: 1.14.1
control plane version: 1.14.1
data plane version: 1.14.1 (16 proxies)

Istio operator shows status as “RECONCILING”
NextGen-ADA-Istio % k get istiooperators.install.istio.io -A
NAMESPACE NAME REVISION STATUS AGE
istio-system ada-istiocontrolplane RECONCILING 141m

istioctl analyze is giving validation succeded
NextGen-ADA-Istio % ~/Downloads/istio-1.14.1/bin/istioctl analyze
:heavy_check_mark: No validation issues found when analyzing namespace: istio-operator.

Istio operator log is looping into the below error
 2022-08-31T20:55:19.880875Z    info    kube    Starting Pilot K8S CRD controller
  2022-08-31T20:55:19.880983Z   info    kube    Pilot K8S CRD controller synced 119µs
  2022-08-31T20:55:19.989339Z   info    installer   Processing resources from manifest: IstiodRemote for CR ada-istiocontrolplane-istio-system-IstiodRemote-https://172.16.0.1:443
  2022-08-31T20:55:19.989367Z   info    installer   EgressGateways is waiting on dependency...
  2022-08-31T20:55:19.989385Z   info    installer   Generated manifest objects are the same as cached for component IstiodRemote.
  2022-08-31T20:55:19.989372Z   info    installer   IngressGateways is waiting on dependency...
  2022-08-31T20:55:19.989397Z   info    installer   Cni is waiting on dependency...
  2022-08-31T20:55:19.989344Z   info    installer   Processing resources from manifest: Base for CR ada-istiocontrolplane-istio-system-Base-https://172.16.0.1:443
  2022-08-31T20:55:19.989395Z   info    installer   Pilot is waiting on dependency...
  2022-08-31T20:55:20.581132Z   info    installer   Generated manifest objects are the same as cached for component Base.
  2022-08-31T20:55:20.581190Z   info    installer   Unblocking dependency Pilot.
  2022-08-31T20:55:20.581211Z   info    installer   Dependency for Pilot has completed, proceeding.
  2022-08-31T20:55:20.581242Z   info    installer   Processing resources from manifest: Pilot for CR ada-istiocontrolplane-istio-system-Pilot-https://172.16.0.1:443
  2022-08-31T20:55:20.774697Z   info    installer   Generated manifest objects are the same as cached for component Pilot.
  2022-08-31T20:55:20.774769Z   info    installer   Unblocking dependency Cni.
  2022-08-31T20:55:20.774804Z   info    installer   Unblocking dependency IngressGateways.
  2022-08-31T20:55:20.774809Z   info    installer   Unblocking dependency EgressGateways.
  2022-08-31T20:55:20.774843Z   info    installer   Dependency for EgressGateways has completed, proceeding.
  2022-08-31T20:55:20.774873Z   info    installer   Processing resources from manifest: EgressGateways for CR ada-istiocontrolplane-istio-system-EgressGateways-https://172.16.0.1:443
  2022-08-31T20:55:20.774886Z   info    installer   Generated manifest objects are the same as cached for component EgressGateways.
  2022-08-31T20:55:20.774894Z   info    installer   Dependency for IngressGateways has completed, proceeding.
  2022-08-31T20:55:20.774910Z   info    installer   Processing resources from manifest: IngressGateways for CR ada-istiocontrolplane-istio-system-IngressGateways-https://172.16.0.1:443
  2022-08-31T20:55:20.774901Z   info    installer   Dependency for Cni has completed, proceeding.
  2022-08-31T20:55:20.774964Z   info    installer   Processing resources from manifest: Cni for CR ada-istiocontrolplane-istio-system-Cni-https://172.16.0.1:443
  2022-08-31T20:55:20.774985Z   info    installer   Generated manifest objects are the same as cached for component Cni.
  2022-08-31T20:55:20.781076Z   info    installer   Generated manifest objects are the same as cached for component IngressGateways.
  - Pruning removed resources
  2022-08-31T20:55:52.087921Z   info    installer   Reconciling IstioOperator
  2022-08-31T20:55:52.467235Z   info    installer   Updating IstioOperator
  2022-08-31T20:55:52.467386Z   info    installer   Detecting third-party JWT support
  2022-08-31T20:55:53.677880Z   info    installer   Applying Kubernetes overlay:
  - kind: PodDisruptionBudget
    name: istiod
    patches:
    - path: spec.minAvailable
      value: 1
  
  
  2022-08-31T20:55:54.072617Z   info    installer   Applying Kubernetes overlay:
  - kind: PodDisruptionBudget
    name: istio-ingressgateway
    patches:
    - path: spec.minAvailable
      value: 3
  
  
  2022-08-31T20:55:54.479135Z   error   analysis    error setting up error handling for kube crdclient: 2 errors occurred:
            * informer has already started
            * informer has already started
```

Answer (score 0):

How upgrade was done? In-place or Canary?
I have already upgraded from v1.10.6 to 1.14.6 using canary method and it went pretty smooth

```
curl -L https://istio.io/downloadIstio | ISTIO_VERSION=1.15.6 TARGET_ARCH=amd64 sh -
istioctl x revision list

Set Existing Istio release to default: istioctl x revision tag set stable --revision 1-14-6 --overwrite

Deploy New version: ./bin/istioctl install --revision 1-15-6 -y -f ../istio-operator.yaml -f ../local-settings/eks/IstioOperatorSpec-values.yaml

Set new version as default: istioctl x revision tag set stable --revision 1-15-6 --overwrite

Verify Istio deployments: istioctl x revision list && istioctl x revision tag list && istioctl ps

Redeploy your application: kc -n NameSpace rollout restart deploy myDeploy && istioctl ps

Tag old revisions: istioctl tag set eol-1-14-6 --revision 1-14-6 --overwrite

Uninstall old un-used revisions: istioctl uninstall -r <OLD_REV> -y
```